# Memory allocation to a struct with a pointer

Tags: c

In foo.h I have:

```
struct Foo_st {
    int a;
    MyObj obj1, obj2;
};

typedef struct Foo_st* Foo;
```

And inside `foo.c` I want to allocate space for my `struct`, so I try:

```
Foo foo1 = (Foo) malloc(sizeof(Foo_st));
```

But I get an error -

> 'Foo_st' undeclared (first use in this function)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hiding pointer semantics behind a typedef is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, struct names must be preceded by `struct`. You want:

```
Foo foo1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Foo_st));
```

Alternatively, replace your `struct Foo_st` declaration with a typedef:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    MyObj obj1, obj2;
} Foo_st;
```

This defines `Foo_st` as an alias to an anonymous `struct` type. Your original allocation statement will then work.

Answer (score 1):

You must *typedef* `struct` to be able to use it without `struct` keyword, just as you did with typedefed pointer:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    MyObj obj1, obj2;
} Foo_st;
typedef Foo_st* Foo;
// note: ^^^^^^^^ there is no struct keyword as Foo_st is already
// a typedef for struct, i.e. struct Foo_st


Foo foo1 = malloc(sizeof(Foo_st));
```

Note: There is no need to cast malloc in C.

Comment: With this solution `typedef struct Foo_st *Foo;` will fail. You removed the `struct` tag, so the ugly pointer typedef must be written `typedef Foo_st *Foo;`, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails in C because the type `Foo_st` is not defined (contrary to C++).

You can correct this in 3 different ways:

- Add the `struct` keyword:

  ```
  Foo foo1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Foo_st));
  ```
- Define the type `Foo_st`:

  ```
  typedef struct Foo_st {
      int a;
      MyObj obj1, obj2;
  } Foo_st;
  typedef struct Foo_st *Foo;

  Foo foo1 = malloc(sizeof(Foo_st));
  ```
- Use the type of the destination pointer (a safer option IMHO):

  ```
  Foo foo1 = malloc(sizeof(*foo1));
  ```

Note that it is considered bad style to hide pointers behind typedefs.  It tends to be error prone and produces non idiomatic code confusing for both the readers and the programmer.